# item problem (I wrote 6, it shows 1)

Tags: support, design

The item 6 of my [answer about lex/yacc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456011/how-to-compile-lex-yacc-files-on-windows) is not correct.

I wrote:

6. six

But (like here) it insists in one.

Also, the items 6.1, 6.2 and 6.3 do not work. I didn't want to **blockquote**. My first attempt was to use **code sample**. It did not work. Then I moved on to sub-itens. Not ok. My third option was blockquote, but I'm unhappy with it. At least it looks like code.

Comment: As for the nested list part, see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85474/145982)

Comment: Please, do not edit it anymore! I'm afraid it became CW. My efforts to earn some points would be in vain. Thanks for the tip. I'll try better in other question.

Comment: If you keep signing your name twice, people will edit it out. So you can avoid that edit towards CW if you don't do that.

Comment: @random I was not going to comment this until you got +1. See, I thank you for the tip. What I don't agree is that it sounds like you support the idea of CW as punishment. CW should be a great thing, not a punishment for a guy who wrote his name and other mistakes (and a lot of typos, I do) in his/her post. That said, thank you for the tip.

Comment: CW isn't punishment. But when a post is floated back to the front page as much as it might from edits, it then is thrown open to a community ownership. When you edit, do as much in one go instead of tiny bumps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it for you, you had too much separation in the text in 5 and so the markdown couldn't be parsed correctly (I think)